# Modern reference on PA degrees?

Tags: logic, reference-request, first-order-logic, computability, peano-axioms

I'm currently trying to work my way around some papers from Jockush et al, and PA degrees come up frequently. I'd be interested in a modern reference/survey summarizing the main results on the subject, if such a thing exists. My usual references don't seem to discuss PA degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking to understand the basic results for $PA$ degrees I would recommend
"Reverse Mathematics: Problems, Reductions and Proofs" by Mummert and
Dzhafarov. In particular look at section 2.8 "Trees and PA degrees" which goes over some of the classical results about $PA$ degrees and basis theorems.

I would also highly recommend
"Turing computability: Theory and Applications" Section 10 will go over similar results and I believe there is a nicer proof of the fact that a set has $PA$ degree if and only if it computes a diagonally non recursive function. It also has a proof that a set with $PA$ degree computes a completion of $PA$. It also has a few basis/non basis theorems which you cannot find on the reverse mathematics book.

Answer (score 3):

Another good source is Diamondstone/Dzhafarov/Soare's survey paper [$\Pi^0_1$ Classes, Peano Arithmetic, Randomness, and Computable Domination](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-51/issue-1/%CE%A0-1-0-Classes-Peano-Arithmetic-Randomness-and-Computable-Domination/10.1215/00294527-2010-009.full). In particular, they go into detail about *weak* basis theorems; while these theorems are admittedly superceded by the low basis theorem (and other "strong" basis theorems), at least in the case of the Kreisel-Shoenfield basis theorem ("Every nonempty $\Pi^0_1$ class has an element $<_T0'$") I think it's still worth seeing the result if only for "flavor."